# Haskell: Delimit a string by chosen sub-strings and whitespace

Tags: haskell

Am still new to Haskell, so apologize if there is an obvious answer to this...

I would like to make a function that splits up the all following lists of strings i.e. [String]:

```
["int x = 1", "y := x + 123"]
["int   x=   1", "y:=   x+123"] 
["int x=1", "y:=x+123"]
```

All into the same string of strings i.e. [[String]]:

```
[["int", "x", "=", "1"], ["y", ":=", "x", "+", "123"]]
```

You can use `map words.lines` for the first [String].

But I do not know any really neat ways to also take into account the others - where you would be using the various sub-strings `"="`, `":="`, `"+"` etc. to break up the main string.

Thank you for taking the time to enlighten me on Haskell :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Prelude comes with a little-known handy function called `lex`, which is a lexer for Haskell expressions.  These match the form you need.

```
lex :: String -> [(String,String)]
```

What a weird type though!  The list is there for interfacing with a standard type of parser, but I'm pretty sure `lex` always returns either 1 or 0 elements (0 indicating a parse failure).  The tuple is `(token-lexed, rest-of-input)`, so `lex` only pulls off one token.  So a simple way to lex a whole string would be:

```
lexStr :: String -> [String]
lexStr "" = []
lexStr s = 
    case lex s of
        [(tok,rest)] -> tok : lexStr rest
        []           -> error "Failed lex"
```

To appease the pedants, this code is in terrible form.  An explicit call to `error` instead of returning a reasonable error using `Maybe`, assuming `lex` only returns 1 or 0 elements, etc.  The code that does this reliably is about the same length, but is significantly more abstract, so I spared your beginner eyes.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) and build a simple grammar for parsing your strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was however hoping for a simple way to do it 'purely', i.e. without other libraries. Oh, and preferably without monads either (because I haven't quite got round to learning about them yet lol).

Comment: Yeah parsec is not great when you're getting started.  I found it reasonably easy to edit a parser someone else had written, but writing my own was beyond my ability for a while.  Requires some comfort with monads.

Comment: Fair enough. It's worth considering as an option though. If you want something else that isn't monadic, you may have to go with a custom option.

Answer (score 0):

how about using words .)
`words :: String -> [String]`
and words wont care for whitespaces..

```
words "Hello World"
= words "Hello     World"
= ["Hello", "World"]
```

Comment: Oh - just seen that I didn't think long enougth: words won't split "y:=" into "y",":=", therefore you'll need to either write your own simple parser(maybe with the help of words :P) or use parsec(which is a good choice to know anyway).

Comment: Plus the use of 'words' was already mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: Wonderfull - I should start using the disorientation of my comments as an indicator to go and get some sleep..